# ASP.NET Parse DateTime result from ajax call to javascript date

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

**Introduction:**

I have a `WebMethod` on my ASP.NET page which returns a `Person` object.
One of the fields is `Birthday` which is a `DateTime` property.

***WebMethod***

```
[WebMethod]
public static Person GetPerson()
{
     Person p = new Person() {
         Id = 1,
         Name = "Test",
         Birthday = new DateTime(1988, 9, 13)
     };

     return p;
}
```

If I make the call using `$.ajax()` I get the response of the server with the `Person` object.

***Ajax call***

```
// Class instance
var Ajaxcalls = function () {

}

_$.extend(Ajaxcalls, {
    GetPerson: function (label) {
        var self = label instanceof _$ ? label : $(label);

        _$.ajax({
            url: 'Default.aspx/GetPerson',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data.d));
                self.html(new Date(Date.parse(data.d.Birthday)));
            }
        });
    }
});
```

***Result:***

```
{"__type":"AjaxTest.Classes.Person","Id":1,"Name":"Test","Birthday":"/Date(590104800000)/"}
```

**Problem**

How do I parse the `Birthday` [/Date(590104800000)/] to a javascript/jQuery date?
I tried `new Date(Date.parse(data.d.Birthday))` but it gives me an `Invalid date`.

Comment: try this code in your webmethod    Birthday = new DateTime(1988, 9, 13).ToLongDateString();

Comment: Birthday is of type DateTime so I can't parse it to a string

Comment: Follow this [blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx)

Comment: @ArunPrasanth works like a charm, if you want post an answer for it!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use `convertToJavaScriptDate()`  function that does this for you:

```js
function convertToJavaScriptDate(value) {
  var pattern = /Date\(([^)]+)\)/;
  var results = pattern.exec(value);
  var dt = new Date(parseFloat(results[1]));
  return (dt.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + dt.getDate() + "/" + dt.getFullYear();
}
```

The `convertToJavaScriptDate()` function accepts a value in `\/Date(ticks)\/` format and returns a date string in `MM/dd/yyyy` format.
Inside, the `convertToJavaScriptDate()` function uses a regular expression that represents a pattern `/Date\(([^)]+)\)/`.
The `exec()` method accepts the source date value and tests for a match in the value. The return value of `exec()` is an array. In this case the second element of the results array (`results[1]`) holds the ticks part of the source date.

For example, if the source value is `\/Date(836418600000)\/` then `results[1]` will be `836418600000`.
Based on this ticks value a JavaScript Date object is formed. The Date object has a constructor that accepts the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970.
Thus `dt` holds a valid JavaScript Date object.
The `convertToJavaScriptDate()` function then formats the date as `MM/dd/yyyy` and returns to the caller.

You can use the `convertToJavaScriptDate()` function as shown below:

```
options.success = function (order) {
 alert("Required Date : " + convertToJavaScriptDate(order.RequiredDate) + ", Shipped Date : " + convertToJavaScriptDate(order.ShippedDate));
};
```

Although the above example uses date in `MM/dd/yyyy` format, you can use other formats also once  Date object is constructed.

reference : [Link](http://www.developer.com/net/dealing-with-json-dates-in-asp.net-mvc.html)

Comment: Here is the version with time included:
`function ToJavaScriptDateTime(value) {
        var pattern = /Date\(([^)]+)\)/;
        var results = pattern.exec(value);
        var dt = new Date(parseFloat(results[1]));
        return dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes() + "  " + ('0' + dt.getDate()).slice(-2) + "." + ('0' + (dt.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "." + dt.getFullYear();
}`

Comment: ive just tried ur method and i got an error 
jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property '1' of null TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null

Comment: Can u provide me a jsfiddle??

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
   _$.ajax({
        url: 'Default.aspx/GetPerson',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data.d));
            var src = data.d.Birthday;
            //Remove all non-numeric (except the plus)
            src = src.replace(/[^0-9 +]/g, ''); 
            //Create date
            var birthDate = new Date(parseInt(src));
            self.html(birthDate);
        }
    });
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chridam/vuq7vmkk/)**

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to using another JavaScript library:

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/asp-net-json-date/

Comment: This is good, if you intend to use the date/time in the javascript ie. some manipulation

Answer (score 1):

Another way of tackling this problem is to make a new element in your person class and then use that. Example

```
public class Person {
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public DateTime Birthday {get;set;}
   public string BirthdayFormat { get {
      return Birthday.toString("dd/MM/YYYY")
   }}
}
```

I would have thought this would be the best way as then all the formating is in one place and where possible you can use. 
`[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/YYYY}")]`

Above the Birthday element, so that displayFor will use the correct formatting.