# Issue passing MVC model array into javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to pass an array from my MVC Model into a javascript array (to use in fullCalendar), however having an issue.

From the below, "myArray" is being populated with the correct amount of items from the model array, but when I try to show obj.DateTime (valid field within the MVC model array) it returns undefined. The undefined alert appears the correct amount of times for items in the array.

Any help at all would be appreciated.

```
var myArray = [];

@foreach (var d in Model.Appointments)
{
    @:myArray.push("@d");
}

myArray.forEach(function (obj) {
    alert(obj.DateTime);
})
```

Comment: What is this `@` syntax…?

Comment: razor syntax. is it incorrect?

Comment: I don't know. We just need to know *what it is*. Because it's neither [tag:javascript] nor [tag:model-view-controller].

Comment: I saw it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23781034/razor-mvc-populating-javascript-array-with-model-array

Comment: Please don't mix JavaScript and C# together. The code you have written is not correct.

Comment: *DateTime* lives in the C#/Razor world, you try to mix things up (there's only *Date* in Javascript). I personnally would fetch the data via Ajax instead of building an ugly Array.push chain.

Comment: What kind of data that `Model.Appointments` and `obj.DateTime` has? If `Model.Appointments` is a `DateTime` array, you don't need `obj.DateTime` - use `new Date(obj)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `@d` for converting your C# object to java-script object directly. You should encode your C# object to make a json value.

This code will encode (Serialize) your C# object to a JSON model.

`@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(d));`

[Here is another question like yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17617263/razor-syntax-error-serializing-asp-net-model-to-json-with-html-raw)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I've been trying stuff like this to no avail.

Can you give me more information on that?  Model.Appointments is my array.

Do you mean something like this?

    @foreach (var d in Model.Appointments)
    {
       @:myArray.push(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(d)));    
    }

Comment: Still gives me "undefined" for the correct amount if items in the array :(

Comment: Do you just have issue with `DateTime` property? You can solve your date converting problem with this post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27314663/asp-net-parse-datetime-result-from-ajax-call-to-javascript-date